Sumo logic query : How to Visualize the Trend of Execution Time
I'm working with Sumo Logic to analyze log data from an application, and I want to visualize the trend of API Response times over time. Specifically, I have logs where the execution time is stored as a numeric value in each entry.
Here is the query I have so far
_sourceCategory=my/source/category "myRestAPIMethod"  
| parse "et=*\n" as execution_time

Sample Log :
[user={userid}] myRestAPIMethod traceId=80w6-4fdc-bew2--d3fs-4df529e6bfaf, reqId=78423423957544b258267a7c208eb0c54, reqCorId=Unknown, respCorId=Unknown, trId=Unknown, statusCode=OK, success=true, et=275


It appeared your parse statement didn't work on the example log you provided so I changed it to be parse regex (because I am regex nerd). But the query below should work for ya. I am doing avg but you could do count or any other type of aggregator.
The important part here is the "timeslice" because it buckets the data into specific time intervals that allow you to track it over time. For instance, if you ran a search back 15 min with a timeslice of 1m, you would have 15 buckets of time. Hope that helps!
_sourceCategory=my/source/category "myRestAPIMethod"   
| parse regex "et\=(?<execution_time>.*?)$" nodrop 
| timeslice 1m // or whatever timeframe you want 
| avg(execution_time) by _timeslice```

